# How do I use query conditions?

Tags: 7, database

I want execute the query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE type = 'AAA' AND id = 'BBB'`.

The following code works.

```
$res = db_select('table', 's')
  ->fields('s')
  ->condition('type', $type)
  ->execute()
  ->fetch();

$res = db_select('table', 's')
  ->fields('s')
  ->condition('id', $id)
  ->execute()
  ->fetch();
```

The following code doesn't work.

```
$res = db_select('table', 's')
  ->fields('s')
  ->condition('type', $type)
  ->condition('id', $id)
  ->execute()
  ->fetch();
```

I get an error about the ID not being unique.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks and sorry. This code works well. I found error in another site.

Comment: Can you explain how the last query doesn't work, have you checked the result of writing the same query in raw SQL?

Comment: According to your update, this has been resolved. Can you please write that as an answer or close this question so that it is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
$res = db_select('table', 's')
->fields('s')
->condition('type', $type)
->condition('id', $id)
->execute()
->fetch();
```

is not faulty in itself. The problem is probably that you don't have a record with matches both id and type. If you want to make an or query, you need to use [`db_or`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_or/7)

Comment: Yes. I want execute query: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE type = 'AAA' AND id = 'BBB'`

Comment: what you did should work then what error do you get