# How to add and condition in Query

Tags: 7, database

I have to fetch nodes where it doesn't have both roles(6,7) in it,at the same time  exactly.

I don't want to show role 7 nodes, but it some times have role 6 attached to it also ,at that time i want to omit those nodes.

This is the query which i wrote for that

```
$nids_result = db_select('node', 'n');
$nids_result->join('users','u','n.uid = u.uid');
$nids_result->join('users_roles','ur','u.uid = ur.uid');
$nids_result->fields('n', array('nid'));
$nids_result->condition('ur.rid', 7, '<>');
$nids_result = $nids_result->execute()->fetchAll();
```

But this is fetching me all nodes including role 7 also,because role 6 is also some times available in the nodes.

How do I write and condition where it checks for both 6 and 7 roles are available and omit those nodes.Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use query conditions?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5854/how-do-i-use-query-conditions)

Comment: The problem is - you are fetching all nodes of users who has a role that is not role 7. So if user has roles 6 and 7, he meets that condition, because he has role 6 that is not role 7. If you have SQL query that fetch what you want it to, we will be able to help you dress it up in Drupal syntax. Please edit that SQL snippet into your question. If you don't know how to obtain your data with pure MySQL, it is not a Drupal question - not yet.

Answer (score 1):

By default it is and condition

```
$nids_result = db_select('node', 'n');
$nids_result->join('users','u','n.uid = u.uid');
$nids_result->join('users_roles','ur','u.uid = ur.uid');
$nids_result->fields('n', array('nid'));
$nids_result->condition('ur.rid', 7, '<>');
$nids_result->condition('ur.rid', 6, '<>');

// if you have devel installed check this.
dpq($nids_result);
$nids_result = $nids_result->execute()->fetchAll();
```

debugging the query with dpq will tell yuo the exact query that you can run on phpmyadmin and can see what you are missing.

**Updated:**

if you need query like

```
SELECT n.nid AS nid
FROM 
{node} n
INNER JOIN {users} u ON n.uid = u.uid
INNER JOIN {users_roles} ur ON u.uid = ur.uid
WHERE ( (ur.rid <> :db_condition_placeholder_0) OR( (ur.rid <> :db_condition_placeholder_1) AND (ur.rid <> :db_condition_placeholder_2) ))
```

Code will be :

```
   $nids_result = db_select('node', 'n');
   $nids_result->join('users','u','n.uid = u.uid');
   $nids_result->join('users_roles','ur','u.uid = ur.uid');
   $nids_result->fields('n', array('nid'));
   $db_or = db_or();
   $db_or->condition('ur.rid', 7, '<>');
   $db_or->condition(db_and()->condition('ur.rid', 7, '<>')->condition('ur.rid', 6, '<>'));
   $nids_result->condition($db_or);
   $src = $nids_result->__toString();
   dpm($src);
```

Comment: This one removes even the role  with 6 nodes too. I want to remove nodes only which has both 6 and 7. Is it possbile then how using query in drupal?

Comment: @Ram and that's why I asked for your ideal SQL... If you would provide it, answerers would know what exactly you want.

Comment: Still it doesnt fetch me expected results. Its fetching all the node(role 7 too). @arpitr

Answer (score 1):

I got through it using sub query and it is successful.

```
$query = "SELECT n.nid AS nid FROM node n INNER JOIN users u ON n.uid = u.uid INNER JOIN users_roles ur ON u.uid = ur.uid where u.uid NOT IN (SELECT u.uid FROM node n INNER JOIN users u ON n.uid = u.uid INNER JOIN users_roles ur ON u.uid = ur.uid where(ur.rid = 7))";

$nids_result_set = db_query($query)->fetchAll();

$nids_result = array();
foreach($nids_result_set as  $nids)
{
   $nids_result[] = $nids;
}
```

This returns all except role 7 nodes.

Where as the issue with below code is that

```
$nids_result->condition(
              db_and()
                ->condition('ur.rid', 7, '<>')
                ->condition('ur.rid', 6, '<>')
);
```

it has seperate entries for each role , so its not escaping for nodes which has both roles 6 and 7. So i have used sub query to get it through.

If any one can find much simple solution will be nice.Thanks all.

Answer (score -1):

Another approach is to use [db_and()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_and/7). Example:

```
$nids_result = db_select('node', 'n');
$nids_result->join('users','u','n.uid = u.uid');
$nids_result->join('users_roles','ur','u.uid = ur.uid');
$nids_result->fields('n', array('nid'));
$nids_result->condition(
              db_and()
                ->condition('ur.rid', 7, '<>')
                ->condition('ur.rid', 6, '<>')
);
$nids_result = $nids_result->execute()->fetchAll();
```

Comment: This one removes even the role with 6 nodes too. I want to remove nodes only which has both 6 and 7. Is it possbile then how using query in drupal?

Comment: @Ram I don't think that you are right.. Because `db_and()` checks for both conditions which are followed after `db_and()`..

Comment: No.Its just returning globaladmin(1) roles nodes alone. Its not fetching me role 6 nodes.